# Why is posterior consistency research focuses only high-dimensionality?

Tags: probability, bayesian, consistency

I have notice that most literature (especially recently) about posterior consistency as $n\rightarrow \infty$ only focuses on areas of high dimensionality i.e. on $p_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ or $p_n=o(n)$ such that $p$ increases with $n$. Why is this? Why not focuses on cases where $p$ remains fixed or small when $n\rightarrow \infty$? Is there a special reason for this?

***Some Refs***

Armagan, A., Dunson, D.B., Lee, J., Bajwa, W.U. and Strawn, N., 2013. Posterior consistency in linear models under shrinkage priors. Biometrika, 100(4), pp.1011-1018.

Song, Q. and Liang, F., 2023. Nearly optimal Bayesian shrinkage for high-dimensional regression. Science China Mathematics, 66(2), pp.409-442.

Jiang, W., 2007. Bayesian variable selection for high dimensional generalized linear models: convergence rates of the fitted densities.

Lee, K., Lee, J. and Lin, L., 2019. Minimax posterior convergence rates and model selection consistency in high-dimensional DAG models based on sparse Cholesky factors. The Annals of Statistics, 47(6), pp.3413-3437.

Comment: In finite-dimensional problems, the Bernstein von Mises theorem establishes the consistency and rate of convergence of the posterior mean (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Bernstein-von_Mises_theorem) to the ML estimator. So, asymptotically, ML and Bayes merge.

Comment: My guess is that the simple case you're interested in (small fixed $p$, increasing $n \to \infty$) was solved with [Doob's proof of Bernstein-Mises](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/467947).

Comment: @mariob6, so for any prior on our variables $\beta$ there will be consistency in finite dimension. However, for infinite dimensions this is true only on special conditions? Is this correct?

Comment: @Durden, so for any prior on our variables $\beta$ there will be consistency in finite dimension. However, for infinite dimensions this is true only on special conditions? Is this correct?

Comment: Well, some hypotheses are needed (e.g., the model is well-specified, and the prior gives mass to neighbourhoods of the true parameter). If $p$ varies with $n$ or $p=\infty$, then standard BvM does not hold and the results must be established case-by-case

Comment: @mariob6 , Does the BvM theorem prove posterior consistency for gamma distribution prior for fixed $p$?

Comment: As mariob6 wrote, it cannot just be _any_ prior on $\beta$. If it happens to have zero probability mass where the population parameter is located, it will always remain zero even as $n \to \infty$. Hence priors should abide by [Cromwell's rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/518462).

Comment: @Durden does the gamma distribution abide by this rule?